# TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null, in RSForms

Tags: javascript

TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null , when i click to form for continue this error will generate , any one please tell me how to fix this error.

when i click to continue button , button call fnction submitform

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

    function submitForm( )
    {  

        var form = document.paywayForm; 
        var errorString = "";
        var recurringURL = "https://www.payway.com.au/SignUp?ClientNumber=Q12882&&merchant_id=23660327&FirstPaymentDate=&CustomerNumber=&returnURL=&AddressRequired=true&PlanName=";
        // NOTE: THIS USES A TEST MERCHANT!!
        var netURL = "https://www.payway.com.au/MakePayment?BillerCode=128827&merchant_id=23660327&payment_amount=";
            if( document.getElementById("RecurringRadio").checked == true )
        {
            if( document.getElementById("frequency1").value == null || document.getElementById("frequency1").value == "" )
            {
                errorString = errorString + " payment frequency";
            }
            if( document.getElementById("SelectAmount1").value == null || document.getElementById("SelectAmount1").value == "" )
            {
                errorString = errorString + " payment amount";
            }
            if( errorString == "" )
            {
                document.location = recurringURL + document.getElementById("frequency1").value + document.getElementById("SelectAmount1").value +
                                    "&Firstname=" + document.getElementById("OneOffAmount1").value;
            }
        }

        else if( document.getElementById("OneOffRadio").checked == true )
        {
            if( document.getElementById("OneOffAmount1").value == null || document.getElementById("OneOffAmount1").value == "" )
            {
                errorString = errorString + "payment amount &nbsp; &nbsp;";
            }
            if( document.getElementById("Firstname").value == null || document.getElementById("Firstname").value == "" )
            {
                errorString = errorString + "name &nbsp; &nbsp;";
            }
            if( document.getElementById("Surname").value == null || document.getElementById("Surname").value == "" )
            {
                errorString = errorString + "surname &nbsp; &nbsp;";
            }
            if( document.getElementById("Address").value == null || document.getElementById("Address").value == "" )
            {
                errorString = errorString + "address &nbsp; &nbsp;";
            }

            if( document.getElementById("Suburb").value == null || document.getElementById("Suburb").value == "" )
            {
                errorString = errorString + "suburb &nbsp; &nbsp;";
            }
            if( document.getElementById("Postcode").value == null || document.getElementById("Postcode").value == "" )
            {
                errorString = errorString + "postcode &nbsp; &nbsp;";
            }
            if( errorString == "" )
            {    

                 var newredirect = netURL + document.getElementById("OneOffAmount1").value +
"&information_fields=Direct_Funds,Title,Firstname,Surname,Address,Suburb,Postcode,State,Country,Phone,Mobile,Email,Bmail,PAWS&payment_reference=00041234" + 
                                    "&Direct_Funds=" + document.getElementById("Direct_Funds").value + 
                                    "&Title=" + document.getElementById("Title").value + 
                                    "&Firstname=" + document.getElementById("Firstname").value + 
                                    "&Surname=" + document.getElementById("Surname").value + 
                                    "&Address=" + document.getElementById("Address").value +
                                    "&Suburb=" + document.getElementById("Suburb").value +
                                    "&Postcode=" + document.getElementById("Postcode").value +
                                    "&State=" + document.getElementById("State").value +
                                    "&Country=" + document.getElementById("Country").value +
                                    "&Phone=" + document.getElementById("Phone").value +
                                    "&Mobile=" + document.getElementById("Mobile").value +
                                    "&Email=" + document.getElementById("Email").value +
                                    "&Bmail=" + document.getElementById("Bmail").value + 
                                    "&PAWS=" + document.getElementById("PAWS").value;
                              //   alert(newredirect);
                                 document.paywayForm.submit();
                /* document.location.href = newredirect;*/
            }
        }
        else
        {   
            errorString = errorString + "You must select a donation type<br/>";
        }

        if( errorString != "" )
        {   
            //alert(errorString);
            var errorEl = document.getElementById("Error");
            errorEl.innerHTML = "<b>The following fields must be completed: </b><br/> " + errorString + "";
            //alert(errorEl.innerHTML);
        }
    }


</script>
```

Comment: can you show html code ?

Comment: It seems your document is not ready when you get `getElementById`.

Comment: asking question must be clear..on seeing your question i have many questions to ask to you.It shouldnt be like that..

Comment: @hallaji right it seems, :gayatri add your script in function and call it on window.onload

Comment: http://fnpw.org.au/ag open this link where having listed form below & thanks to respond

Comment: @gayatri You should include the relevant markup in the question along with the JavaScript. But, it seems that no element exists with `id="frequency1"`, so it will return `null`. There is an `id="frequency"` (without the `1`), however.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski yep, there is no id="frequency1"

Comment: Are you referring to the Frequency `select` box field?

Comment: I just posted an answer assuming you mean payment frequency select drop down.

Comment: i have solved issue actually their is issue of not passing ID to fields , now i have assigned to all fields id and it's working fine

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are looking for the drop down with `name` as `frequency`, you should be getting the element by name -

```
if( document.getElementsByName("frequency")[0] == null 
    || document.getElementsByName("frequency")[0].selectedIndex == 0  ) 
{
    /* error occuer here */
    errorString = errorString + " payment frequency";
}
```

Since you already have the drop down on the page, the check for NULL will always be false and the selected value will be the first drop down value so the selected index will always be 0 if user doesn't change it. So, there is no point in checking for above as the element will not be null and the selected index will be 0 for frequency `week`.

What you should instead be doing is add another option to the select which is blank and then use the below code to see if user has selected a value for frequency of payment.

HTML should look like

```
<select name="frequency" class="drop" style="width: 80px;">
    <option value="" selected>Select frequency</option>
    <option value="Weekly">Week</option>
    <option value="Fortnightly">Fortnightly</option>
    <option value="Monthly">Month</option>
</select>
```

and you JS code check should look like

```
if( document.getElementsByName("frequency")[0].selectedIndex == 0  ) 
{
    /* error occuer here - frequency not selected */
    errorString = errorString + " payment frequency";
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 as I was about to post the exact same option. One additional thing I wanted to suggest is adding a `id='frequency'` to this `select` box but it has to be noted that an above `div` already has that `id`.

Comment: i have solved issue actually their is issue of not passing ID to fields , now i have assigned to all fields id and it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<script>
    window.onload=function(){

    if( document.getElementById("frequency1").value == null || document.getElementById("frequency1").value == "" ) /* error occuer here */
    {
    errorString = errorString + " payment frequency";
    }

    };
</script>
```

Comment: @gayatri are you trying to get values of select box named frequency?

Comment: thanks shadow i have solved issue actually their is issue of not passing ID to fields , now i have assigned to all fields id and it's working fine

Comment: @gayatri Cheers then :-)

Comment: @gayatri your website is not active it seems rathva4u.com

Comment: you their ? i have another javascript issue

Comment: @gayatri yep, always welcum :-)

Comment: http://www.communitymash.com/2012-10-19-05-40-05 on this link i have javascript error occur : TypeError: item1 is undefined while in home page this error will not generate. it's left menu spilt issue

Comment: var item1 = $("."+$("#left").children("li")[i].className+" a").html(); Do you want to get the class name of li and append with ' a' and get the html content of element who belong to this class

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer is case insensitive as far as ID's are concerned. But not Mozilla and others. Make sure that the ID is spelled correctly in your code. Must exactly match in case.

Comment: This is not an answer mate. It is a comment.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when your element is null(doesn't exist). So javascript cannot get its value.you can get the element first and then check if it is null or not and then ask for its value rather than just asking for the value directly without knowing if the element is visible on the HTML or not.

```
element1 = document.getElementById("frequency1");

if(element1 != null)
{
    //code to set the value variable and test the value not to be empty.
}
```

Comment: i have solved issue actually their is issue of not passing ID to fields , now i have assigned to all fields id and it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this frustrating problem too, and you may wish to change the order of the elements too, so that the elemnt comes before the JS. 
It could be that the JS can't find the element yet, because it hasn't loaded in time, or you could load it and execute your JS with a document.ready feature or similar.

Typically our pages work like this:

```
<head>
<scripts>
<body>
<elements>
<end>
```

Maybe if you try it like this it'll work:

```
<head>
<scripts>
<body>
<elements>
<script for elements>
<end>
```